# Best way to initialize QString

Tags: c++, string, qt, qstring

What is the best way to initialize `QString`:

```
   QString name = "name";
   // or
   QString nameL = QStringLiteral("name");
   // or
   QString nameLL = QLatin1String("name");
   // or something else...
```

Comment: Good writeup: [QStringLiteral explained](https://woboq.com/blog/qstringliteral.html)

Comment: @Swordfish Thanks for the link, interesting article.

Comment: Generally speaking: If you want to initialize a `QString` from a char*, use `QStringLiteral`. If you want to pass it to a method, check if that method has an overload for `QLatin1String` - if yes you can use that one, otherwise fall back to `QStringLiteral`. The only exception for both cases is an empty string - simply use `QString()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`QStringLiteral` will have the lowest runtime overhead. It is one of the few literal `QString` initializations with O(1) cost. `QLatin1String` will be pretty fast, but have O(N) cost in length of the string. The intiialization with C string literal will have the highest O(N) cost and is equivalent to IIRC `QString::fromUtf8("…")`. The 2nd and 3rd initialization also *adds* an O(N) memory cost, since a copy of the string is made (!). Whatever “savings” you made in executable size thus promptly vanish as the program starts up :(

Initialization via `QStringLiteral` wins, although you may want to leverage modern C++11 custom literals to make it shorter. Resist the urge to use a macro for it: it’d be an extremely misguided approach as you pollute the global namespace with a short symbol.

Comment: QString str (QString());

Comment: @Mike That's pointless, though. `QString str;` is all you need: it's a value type, and has a valid value after default-construction.